# Book about a man that can slow down time to almost a stand-still

Tags: story-identification, books

It's about a man that can slow down time to "almost" static but not quite (maybe a million times slower). He does unusual things like freezing time while driving a car at 50 mph, and then opens the car door and walks around on the spongy, blurry road. He then gets back into the car and restarts. There's a lot of adult content so not good for anyone under 18.

Comment: Could you take a look at [this guide](https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/a/9337/58193) and see if there is anything else you can [edit] in? For example, when did you read this? Was it new at the time?

Answer (score 14):

That's *[The Fermata](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Fermata)* by Nicholson Baker.

Your memory of the spongy road is quite accurate. The protagonist hypothesises that it is because even though time is stopped, there still is a speed difference.

The protagonist discovers his ability to stop / slow down time (which he calls a "fermata"), then gradually learns how to control it better. He mainly uses his ability to facilitate sexual encounters. He also records compact cassettes while in the fermata, then leaves them for others to find.

In the end he loses his ability to his then current sexual partner.

---

I just learned through the Wikipedia article that Neil Gaiman and Robert Zemeckis [have drafted a screenplay](https://www.neilgaiman.com/p/Cool_Stuff/Essays/Essays_About_Neil/Neil_Gaiman's_Film_Work).

Comment: Do you have the book handy? If so, you might want to find the scene about driving in slowed down time.

Comment: @TheLethalCarrot I don't (I don't have it) and the highly NSFW content makes me hesitant to search for it.

Comment: Fair enough, I think this is correct though. The Wikipedia summary does seem to suggest this is the one from the OPs comment "There's a lot of adult content so not good for anyone under 18."

Comment: Yes you are right, it is The Fermata! Thanks SQB
And also thanks @TheLethalCarrot - I hope you get to read it, it's an odd but interesting read. I'm not sure I can mark your answer as correct as its a temp thingy.

Comment: This was marked as accepted in what "appears" to be the OP using a different account in a now [deleted answer](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/a/194159/58193). However, it isn't 100% clear if this is the same user so it shouldn't be taken to mean this is correct until confirmed properly.

Comment: I remember the car scene. It involved the protagonist writing a story for a random person on the road and then recording it on a tape cassette and inserting it into their cars tape deck.

Comment: @TheLethalCarrot Check the gravatars of the OP and answerer: it's the same user.

Comment: @Randal'Thor I saw that but it’s better to be on the safe side just in case.